# Parsing simple text file and integrate content in bash script

Tags: bash, parsing, sed, awk

I want to automatically parse a text file with a content like this:

```
car 12345 W
train 54321 D
```

To be integrated in a new bash file. The content after that should look like that:

```
curl http://example.com/?vehicle=car&number=12345&period=W
curl http://example.com/?vehicle=train&number=54321&period=D
```

My problem is that I really don't now how to realize that or which program to use, sed, awk, etc..

What do I have to do?

Comment: bash, awk, sed... all fine.. what's the problem. please show some code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's probably the funniest answer: assume your file is `file.txt`, then just do this:

```
printf 'curl http://example.com/?vehicle=%s&number=%s&period=%s\n' $(<file.txt)
```

It:

- is 100% pure bash,
- has no explicit loops
- is the shortest answer
- is very funny

Hope this helps `:)`

Comment: This will fail for large files, because it will exceed the maximum number of arguments.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
while read vehicle number period ; do
    echo curl http://example.com/\?vehicle="$vehicle"\&number="$number"\&period="$period"
done < input.txt
```

Comment: +1 It would actually look better if you place everything around doublequotes and just use `${var}` formats.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use `sed` to interleave the URL arguments with other parts. Guessing from the sample you posted:

```
sed 's/\([a-z]*\) \([0-9]*\) \([A-Z]\)/curl http:\/\/example.com\/?vehicle=\1\&number=\2\&period=\3/'
```

Comment: @ceving If you say so, I believe you even without a proof. My comment is then directed towards whomever did.